# Get annotation value dynamically, not hard coding the class/method name to get the annotation value

Tags: java, reflection

I have some tests running on testNG, which will have test data type annotated on the test method, i am using a common a method to read the test data based on the annotation value in test methods. Problem here is, i can not specify the class or method name to read the annotation as there will be different/multiple test methods from different classes that will be reading the test data. So i am looking for a way to read the annotation dynamically from this common method, based on which test method is seeking for the test data.

Please have a look on the below code snippet for more clarity.

```
public class MyClass1 {

    @Test
    @testDataParam(testDataType="excel")
    public void test1() {

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.getValue();
        //Some test that reads from specified test data type
    }

}

public class MyClass2 {

    @Test
    @testDataParam(testDataType="json")
    public void test2() {

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.getValue();
        //Some test that reads from specified test data type
    }

}

public class GetTestData {

    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface testDataParam {
        String testDataType();
    }

}

public class DataTable {

    public void setDataTable() {

        // get annotation from test methods, test methods will be different for
        // different test, so i can not mention specific class or method here to read
        // annotation.

        // if test data type is excel, read data from excel
        // if test data type is json, read data from json
    }

    public String getValue() {

        // return value from specified data type excel/json
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your annotated methods will all be without parameters, you can simply ask for stack trace and lookup the methods to locate the annotation.

Here is an example:

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface TestData {
    String value();
}
```

```
public class MyClass1 {
    @TestData("Foo")
    public void test1() {
        Util.doSomething();
    }
}
```

```
public class Util {
    public static void doSomething() {
        for (StackTraceElement stackTrace : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
            try {
                TestData annotation = Class.forName(stackTrace.getClassName())
                                           .getDeclaredMethod(stackTrace.getMethodName())
                                           .getAnnotation(TestData.class);
                if (annotation != null)
                    System.out.println("Test data is: " + annotation.value());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Ignore
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you execute the `test1()` method, you get this output:

```
Test data is: Foo
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve this problem with a coding problem I did. I only have half the solution.

To get the classes, I used [Fast Classpath Scanner](https://github.com/lukehutch/fast-classpath-scanner) which gets all the classes and subclasses declared in a package. Then you perform `result.classNamesToClassRefs(result.getNamesOfAllClasses())` to get the List of Classes

---

The `Class` type has a method that allows you to get all the declared methods inside it, namely `[class object].getDeclaredMethods()`. To get the `Class`, you need to do either `MyClass1.class` or `new MyClass1().getClass()`

To get the desired method from the `Method` array returned from `getDeclaredMethods()`, you can invoke `method.getAnnotation(Test.class)` and check if it is null. If it isn't, you can then use:

```
testDataParam annotation = method.getAnnotation(testDataParam.class);
Sting dataType = annotation.testDataType();
```

to extract the data type from the annotation.

In full:

```
//Put the classes into a Class<?> array
FastClasspathScanner scanner = new FastClasspathScanner("YOUR PACKAGE HERE");
ScanResult result = scanner.scan();

for (Class<?> cls : result.classNamesToClassRefs(result.getNamesOfAllClasses())) {
    for (Method method : cls.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        if (method.getAnnotation(Test.class) != null) {
            testDataParam annotation = method.getAnnotation(testDataParam.class);
            Sting dataType = annotation.testDataType();
            //Do what you want with this
        }
    }
}
```